# Как отображать media файлы в production среде, в Django?

Tags: python, django

Я создал Django приложение и развернул его на хостинге. У меня перестали работать static и media файлы. Со static файлами я проблему решил с помощью Whitenoise. Но что делать с отображением media? При DEBUG=True всё работает, а при DEBUG=False нет. Есть какие ни будь сервисы по типу Whitenoise, только для media? Облачные хранилища по типу Amazon S3 использовать не хочется.

PS: Хостинг - Amvera Cloud, Django 5.0.2, для запуска используется gunicorn. Я новичок и только учусь по этому без хейта пожалуйста. Помогите пожалуйста