# Куда класть media на хостинге Amvera Cloud?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, gunicorn

У меня есть приложение на Django. Я решил развернуть его на хостинге Amvera. Вопрос в том, куда складывать media файлы? Ведь Django её не обслуживает. static можно раздавать с помощью whitenoise, но что делать с media? Я не нашел ответа в документации самого Amvera Cloud. Может помочь мой файл конфигурации (amvera.yml) :

```
meta:
  environment: python
  toolchain:
    name: pip
  version: 3.10
build:
  requirementsPath: requirements.txt
run:
  command: gunicorn borib.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:80
  persistenceMount: /data
  containerPort: 80
```

Вот, что у меня в settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/data/media'
```

Может кто то уже пользовался amvera cloud и разворачивал Django? Не понимаю куда девать media...

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1570469